# Plain text not received in Outlook from AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, text, amazon-ses, email-formats

I need to receive HTML and Plain text formats according to the email client configuration. I have configured Outlook to receive plain text following the link [Plain text support in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/read-email-messages-in-plain-text-16dfe54a-fadc-4261-b2ce-19ad072ed7e3)
I have the below params for AWS SES, but Outlook still receives HTML format. How can I receive email in plain text format from SES?

```
 {
    Destination: {
        /* required */
        ToAddresses: ['email', /* more items */]
    },
    Message: {
        /* required */
        Body: {
            /* required */

            Text: {
                Charset: "UTF-8",
                Data: `plain text`
            },
            Html: {
                Charset: "UTF-8",
                Data: `<h3>Hi $\{name\}!</h3><br/>
<p>Your OTP for Something Something Service Hub is:<em> $\{otp\}</em>
</p><br/>
<p>Regards,<br/>
Something Something Service Hub Team</p>`
            },
        },
        Subject: {
            Charset: 'UTF-8',
            Data: `$\{otp\} is the  OTP for Something Something Service Hub!`
        }
    },
    Source: 'email',
    /* required */
    ReplyToAddresses: ['email', /* more items */],
};
```

Comment: Try just passing only `Text` field and place all your content inside `Text` field.